# Printing multiple values on the same line

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to parse a JSON document and print a couple of values on the same line. Is there a way to take the following document:

```
{
  "fmep": {
    "foo": 112,
    "bar": 234324,
    "cat": 21343423
  }
}
```

And spit out:

```
112 234324
```

I can get the values I want but they are printed on separate lines:

```
$ echo '{ "fmep": { "foo": 112, "bar": 234324, "cat": 21343423 } }' | jq '.fmep|.foo,.bar'

112  
234324
```

If there is an example somewhere that shows how to do this I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The easiest way in your example is to use [String Interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-(foo)) along with the `-r` option. e.g.

```
echo '{ "fmep": { "foo": 112, "bar": 234324, "cat": 21343423 } }' | \
jq -r '.fmep| "\(.foo) \(.bar)"'
```

produces

```
112 234324
```

You may also want to consider putting the values in an array and using [@tsv](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions:%7E:text=escaped%20by%20repetition.-,%40tsv,-%3A) e.g.

```
echo '{ "fmep": { "foo": 112, "bar": 234324, "cat": 21343423 } }' | \
jq -r '.fmep | [.foo, .bar] | @tsv'
```

which produces tab-separated

```
112 234324
```

Comment: That works like a charm! It looks like the jq "-j" option works as well but string interpolation is more readable.

Comment: Maybe its just me, but doing TSV-conversion feels like doing it badly. Using string interpolation feels the natural way of outputting data.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the syntax using joined output (`-j`):

```
jq -j '.fmep | .foo, " ", .bar, "\n"' payload.json
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's say our JSON (*example.json*) looks like this:
{
"hello":"world",
"foo":"bar"
}

In order to join a few fields into the same line you can:

```
$ jq -j '.hello,.foo' example.json
```

This will result in

```
worldbar
```

Want to add a delimiter? let's say a space

```
$ jq -j '.hello," ",.foo' example.json
```

This will result in

```
world bar
```

*Just make sure you are using jq version 1.5 or higher